# Is there a way in Xcode 4 to find objects which have not been dealloced?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, xcode4, nsmutablearray

In my app, I have random objects floating around in my view which I had THOUGHT I deleted through [NSMutableArray replaceObjectAtIndex:index withObject:newObject]
BUT it turns out that after I made alpha = 0.5, those replaced old objects were still there. Since I am using the new xcode 4 with ARC, I can't check whether those objects have failed to dealloc or something.
So, is there any technique or command in xcode 4 (yes the new one) that can help with this sorta debugging?

Also, in xcode 4, will removing an object from view delete it? I used [object.view removeFromSuperView] to get them out of the view, but I have no idea whether they are still existing somewhere else, causing memory leaks.

Comment: If they are still visible, they have not been correctly removed from their super view.

Comment: I haven't started messing with ARC yet, but in pre-ARC times, the built-in clang "Analyze" function will report things like this.

Comment: Mike: When I remove them from super view, they disappear. But problem is: Just because you can't see it, does that mean it's dealloced?  

Dan: How do I go about (finding and) using "Analyze"?

Comment: Also, I was under the impression that NSMutableArray ReplaceObject dealloced the replaced object. Does anyone know for a fact whether it is or not?

Comment: Removing an object from an NSMutableArray, regardless of how you do it, *releases* that object. Whether it dealloc's it or not is entirely dependent on whether there are other references. I'd suggest reading (or re-reading) Apple's documentation on memory management if you are unclear on the difference between release and dealloc/"delete".

Comment: Yea, I am a bit unclear on that. Since I'm talking about making the object and its subviews get cleared from screen, I need dealloc, right? Release will only release a reference to the object.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to get help in that area is using Instruments (specifically the allocations tool) in order to 'debug' which objects are still alive, and what their call-stack is. It takes some fiddling around, but it is a powerful set of tools.

Answer (score 0):

I agree that using Instruments(/Developer/Applications/Instruments) is the way to go, but you can also set breakpoints in your code. See the 'Debugging and Analyzing Your Code' section in the '[Xcode 4 Transition Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/Xcode4TransitionGuide/Debugging/Debugging.html)' I would also suggest iterating through the super view's subview using the view's property subviews, like so.

```
    for ( UIView *view in self.view.subviews) {
        // Check your objects here.
}
```

As to memory management, if you use new, alloc, mutablecopy or copy you own it and need to take care of the object's memory allocation and deallocation. You can either use [auto release](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Protocols/NSObject_Protocol/Reference/NSObject.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/NSObject/autorelease) or release it in your dealloc method. The uiview method removeFromSuperView will release your object.

Hope that helps, fragilecat

Comment: So if I [Class alloc] init] in Xcode 4, I must dispose of it myself?

Comment: Forgot to add you could also check and see how many references to the the objects in question there are. Objective c uses reference counting policy, so there is a chance another object has a reference to the objects you are trying to release.

Comment: Yes you must, you own the object and must manage it's memory allocation.

Comment: You could also use [[[class alloc] autorelease] and the system will 'try' to manage the objects allocation and deallocation.

Comment: Sorry that should have been [[[class alloc] init] autorelease].

Comment: So ARC doesn't auto release for me?

Comment: Not sure on that one, but check this link, [link](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/AutomaticReferenceCounting.html)ARC

Comment: Autorelease is not allowed in ARC mode. I can fix the views now using view removeFromSuperView, but what about objects? I have objects with variables inside, and I have objects with views inside. After I remove those views from sight, what about the rest of the object?